# how can I deal with fetch API result withen useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to know what I have missed here: After setFriend I tried to console log (friend) but I got an empty array, could someone please explain that :)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from './Button';

const Friend = () => {
    const [friend, setFriend] = useState({})

    async function getFriend() {
        try{
            const response = await fetch('https://www.randomuser.me/api?results=1')
            const result = await response.json()
            await setFriend(result)
            console.log(friend)

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button getFriend={getFriend}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Friend;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use `useEffect`

```
async function getFriend() {
        try{
            const response = await fetch('https://www.randomuser.me/api?results=1')
            const result = await response.json()
            await setFriend(result)
            console.log(friend)

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

    }

useEffect(() => {
    getFriend()
}, [])
```

Comment: That is amazing, thanks @Medet Tleukabiluly,... I have to read about useEffect :))

Comment: @razmo: You just cannot use useEffect like that. You need to know how to use or else you may have memory leaks.

Comment: @Shivartaj : thanks for your reply. Could you please explain what is the best way to use useEffec

Comment: @Shivaraj what do you mean you cannot use like that? Thats the correct usage of effect